# Corolla 2001 with P1346 code

Tags: toyota, corolla, camshaft-position-sensor

I have a Corolla 2001 with check engine light code p1346. I had same code about 10 months ago which kinda got fixed by replacing the cam shaft position sensor but i used to see that code as pending and goes away but now it comes back after reseting the ECU couple times. I bought the car a year ago and since then i replaced spark plugs, remanufactured set of injectors, gas cap, PCV vlave, O2 sensor (used from junkyard). All these parts replaced due to another code i had sometimes (P0171) high positive fuel trims. The trims got to around 10% after all that work done but now i have the P1346 keep coming back. The engine has some rattle and knockish noise with cold starts which diminishes after warming up. I use 10w30 full synthetic oil. Do you think the engine has a timing issue or is it the cam shaft position sensor going bad again after 10 months only[image]
[image]
Thanks!

Comment: Is the engine running well, or are you having issues?

Comment: Engine is running fine but sometimes the RPM dips little bit in stop light around (600rmp) and some rattle and knocking noise on cold starts. Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that in last two times the check engine light came with this code happend after going up hill with AC on. This car had some dirty oil issue when i first bought it, do you think it is a vvti blockage somewhere in the system?